# Why won't this simple program compile?

Tags: c

I'm just trying to do a simple test run of executing a program and passing it two parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    start = atoi(argv[1]);
    stop = atoi(argv[2]);
    for(start; start < stop; start++)
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
}
```

Why is this not working? When I compile it says start and stop is not declared. And when I try to run it as a executable like this `./file 3 5` it says "." is not recognized as an internal or external command. I'm using mingw on my widows cmd prompt. Any ideas why it wont run like I want? That being: compiling, entering executable `./file 3 5` then it running like normal?

Comment: Because you haven't given start or stop types. They need to be `int start` and `int stop` the first time you assign to them.

Comment: Do you know what variable declarations are? Because you don't have any.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you *didn't* declare start or stop. You have to declare variables before you can use them. They don't just show up out of thin air.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int start = atoi(argv[1]);
    int stop = atoi(argv[3]);
    for(start; start < stop; start++)
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: argv[2], typo, sorry my mobile is bugging out.

Answer (score 2):

The windows shell you're using is a basically DOS-ish thing. `./prog` doesn't work because the slash is not a directory separator. You have to use `.\prog`, or just `prog` because `.` is always implicitly in the `PATH`.

This is in addition to your lack of declaration of `start` and `stop` which is well covered by the other answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are actually using *start* and *stop* variables without declaring them.

You are passing to the main two strings (*argv[1]* and *argv[2]*) that are supposed to be integers; as a consequence you need your *start* and *stop* variables to be integers as well.

Therefore you have two options (which are the same, just pick your favourite one):

```
int start = atoi(argv[1]);
int stop = atoi(argv[2]);
```

or

```
int start, stop;
start = atoi(argv[1]);
stop = atoi(argv[2]);
```